# How to get the value of variable in different javascript file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

**test.html**

```
 <script src="jsv/test1.js"></script>
 <script src="jsv3/test2.js"></script>
```

**test1.js:**

```
(function ($) {
  var settings = {
    taphold_threshold: 750,
    hold_timer: null,
    tap_timer: null
  };)
};
```

**test2.js:**

```
var Navigation = {
  init: function () {
    self = this;
    $('#button').live(tapMode, function () {
      alert(settings[taphold_threshold]);
    });
  }
}
```

I would like to get the value of settings : taphold_threshold, but it seems i can not get the value by simply alert it. test2.js is the caller and test1.js is callee. It should be some scope problem. How to get the value (750) ? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is indeed scope - `settings` will be in an anonymous scope which is not available outside of the closure.

You could change **test1** to have a sort of "namespace" - say something like `global` (although I would personally use a more descriptive name than global).

```
var global = {};
global.settings = {
    taphold_threshold: 750,
    hold_timer: null,
    tap_timer: null
  };
```

The from **test2** you can use:

```
alert(global.settings.taphold_threshold);
```

Comment: your `var global` is actually again a local scoped variable.

Comment: @metadings - indeed, but it's not enclosed within a closure so will be accessible from the main scope.

Answer (score 2):

Your code hints at a namespace pattern but falls slightly short.

You might like to consider something like this

```
var TAP = (function($) {//functional namespace
  var settings = {
    hold_threshold: 750,
    hold_timer: null,
    timer: null
  };
  var setSettings = function(s) {
    settings = $.extend(settings, s);
  };
  var getSettings = function() {
    return settings;
  };
  return {
    set: setSettings,
    get: getSettings
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Thus, `TAP` has private member `settings` and public members `set()` and `get()`. You will see that further private and public members are easily added.

Now you have a mechanism to both set and get TAP settings from anywhere that TAP is within scope:

```
TAP.set({hold_threshold: 500});

var Navigation = {
  init: function () {
    self = this;
    $('#button').live(tapMode, function () {
      alert(settings[TAP.get().hold_threshold]);
    });
  }
}
```

With `TAP` as a member in the global namespace, it's public methods are available in all scopes.

More typically, you will use the MODULE pattern, which puts just **one** PROJECT member into the global namespace, containing any number of MODULES, each containing any number of functional NAMESPACES, for example :

```
var MYPROJECT = {};//global
MYPROJECT.MODULE1 = {};
MYPROJECT.MODULE1.TAP= (function($) {
  var settings = {
    hold_threshold: 750,
    hold_timer: null,
    timer: null
  };
  var setSettings = function(s) {
    settings = $.extend(settings, s);
  };
  var getSettings = function() {
    return settings;
  };
  return {
    set: setSettings,
    get: getSettings
  };
})(jQuery);
```

By convention, MYPROJECT, its MODULES and its functional NAMESPACES are capitalized.

Answer (score 1):

Since `var settings` is defined in **test1.js** inside a closure, hence the problem exists.

You might want to define the settings variable as

```
window.settings = ...
```

OR

```
window['settings'] = ...
```

So now `settings` would be defined as a global variable.

Comment: Just wanted to know what was the problem with the answer, so that I can correct myself

Comment: +1 because you have -1 for not being wrong, in fact, you're right with one exception: when using [] you need to quote the name `window['settings']`

Answer (score 1):

`settings` is nested within a closure and it cannot be accessed from the outside. One solution is to remove the closure so that it becomes a global object. Another solution is to assign it to the window object, same as making the variable global but this works from inside closures. Here is an example:

```
(function ($) {
    window.my_namespace = window.my_namespace || {};
    window.my_namespace.settings = {
        taphold_threshold: 750,
        hold_timer: null,
        tap_timer: null
    };
});

var Navigation = {
    init: function () {
        self = this;
        $('#button').live(tapMode, function () {
            alert(my_namespace.settings[taphold_threshold]);
        });
    }
};
```